# Where does Plants vs. Zombies store its savegames?

Tags: pc, plants-vs-zombies

I'd like to backup my Plants vs. Zombies savegames.

Where are they saved?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[From this blog: AndrewBlock.Net](http://andrewblock.net/?p=547)

> **Steam version**
>
> - Vista/Window 7: `C:\ProgramData\Steam\PlantsVsZombies\userdata`
> - XP: `C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\plants vs
>     zombies\userdata`
>
> **Non-Steam version**
>
> - Vista/Windows 7: `C:\ProgramData\PopCap
>     Games\PlantsVsZombies\userdata`
> - XP: `C:\Program Files\PopCap Games\Plants vs. Zombies\userdata`
>
> So, locate the files on the computer
>   you're currently playing on. Then,
>   copy all of the .dat files into the
>   directory on the computer you want to
>   start playing on (in my case, I copied
>   them from the netbook to the desktop).
>   Note that this will overwrite any
>   progress on the target computer, but
>   you probably figured that already.
>
> Note: I can't vouch for XP, but in my
>   Windows 7 + Steam scenario, the
>   'C:\ProgramData\Steam\PlantsVsZombies\userdata'
>   folder is hidden. I had to turn on
>   viewing of hidden files: Computer >
>   Organize > Folder and Search Options >
>   View > Show hidden files, folders, and
>   drives (works in Vista too). In XP
>   it's My Computer > Tools > Folder
>   Options > View > Show hidden files —
>   or something like that.

Comment: If you bought the game elsewhere than Steam, it will save its game under ProgramData\Reflexive\PlantsVsZombies\userdata

Answer (score 6):

I found my saved games in this folder: `C:\ProgramData\Reflexive\PlantsVsZombies\userdata`.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for Steam or other re-sellers of the Plants vs. Zombies game, but if you purchased it from Popcap Games (the creators), the saved game is in the following location:

- Windows 8 / Windows 7 / Vista:  C:\ProgramData\Plants vs. Zombies\userdata
- XP:  C:\Program Files\Plants vs. Zombies\userdata

Answer (score 1):

I found it in "C:\ProgramData\PopCap Games\PlantsVsZombies\userdat